# Another CRSF token error while uploading file in django

Tags: django, forms, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a csv file in my view. I included csrf token however I'm directly taking 403 error when I try to upload a file. Here is my view and template:

**MY FORM HTML**

```
<div class="file-boxes">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" encoding="multipart/form-data" id="upload-csv" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.csv}}
            <!-- <input class="input-file" id="fileInput" type="file" size="14" name="csv_upload" onchange="this.form.submit()"> -->
        </form> 
    </div>
```

**MY FORM**

```
class DeliveryDataForm(forms.Form):
    csv = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'size:':14,'onchange':'this.form.submit()'}))
```

**MY VIEW**

```
def upload_data(request):
    ...
    form = DeliveryDataForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        import pdb
        pdb.stack_trace()
        form = DeliveryDataForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        return HttpResponse('asd')

    return render_to_response(template,context)
```

I know there are some missing parts in the view but the strange thing is, it never enters the if part. Any idea ?

Comment: does this happen even if you render form as '{{ form }}' and not '{{ form.csv }}'?

Comment: yes, I tried {{form}} as well and still getting the error

Comment: And did you read the error page, or [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/csrf/), where it clearly states that you need to use RequestContext in order to get the csrf key?

Comment: what if you remove `onchange` script and add regular submit button and submit form? (just to be sure it is not caused by that)

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko yes I've tried that too

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Thank you, the reason is RequestContext, it works now.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# ...
# return render_to_response(template,context)
return render(request,'index.html',context)
```